# Detect musical note with android device

Tags: android, audio

Is it possible to get the current musical note from a whistle with the microphone of an android device?
I'm looking for a library android compatible witch can do that kind of stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this open source [guitar tuner](http://code.google.com/p/open-guitar/).

You should find what you need in [TunerEngine.java](http://code.google.com/p/open-guitar/source/browse/trunk/src/com/jordanro/guitarweirdo/tuner/audioUtil/TunerEngine.java).